Identify Dynamic Requests made by javascript for Purpose of Web Scraping
I would like to do web scraping to this webpage, and the following is what I have done trying to find the dynamic URL that is behind the javascipt of that page.

Open the page in Google Chrome.
"Inspect" from the right click menu.
Switch to the "Network" tab.
Triger the javascript fetch by F5 key.
Check the "Fetch/XHR" sub-tab, and find a "jobs" that has a "Response" (sub sub tab) that contains json of the jobpostings.
Go to the "Headers" sub sub tab, and the "Request URL" is https://cheo.wd10.myworkdayjobs.com/wday/cxs/cheo/External_Site/jobs
Open the above request url, resulting a response reads as

{
  "errorCode": "HTTP_500",
  "errorCaseId": "E46F9EM40PAYV2",
  "httpStatus": 500,
  "locale": "en-GB,en-US;q\u003d0.9,en;q\u003d0.8,zh-CN;q\u003d0.7,zh;q\u003d0.6",
  "message": "",
  "messageParams": {}
}

In the past, I have had some successes following the above steps find the dynamic urls for other webpages. For this page (and lots of other ones), I must be missing some thing. My questions are

How are the steps for one to get the dynamic url for the purpose of web scraping the mentioned webpage?
Are there any detailed tutorials on this topic?

By the way, I am using PHP and Simple_html_dom when I do web scraping.

Look carefully at the outbound request in your network tab. You're going to notice that's a POST request with a JSON payload containing the following body: {appliedFacets: {}, limit: 20, offset: 0, searchText: ""}. This isn't something you can simply open in a new tab, as the endpoint doesn't respond to GET calls. Additionally, if you open up the response tab in your network inspector for this request, you'll see that the response body is JSON, not HTML. You should look into PostMan to test out remote requests, and tailoring your scraper to use the exact method and request structure.

@maiorano84 Thank you for pointing out PostMan. That would be some thing I will learn and try.

My question got down votes. I hope those guys point out the problems as well. That way, I can ask smarter questions.

It's likely that you were downvoted due to your question being too broad. It's not that it's not "smart", there's just too much to go over and too many ways to achieve what you want to give you a single answer that's going to benefit anyone else. Narrow down the scope of what you're asking to a Minimal, Reproducible Example with code that you've attempted, and you're likely to get better answers. You can try to edit your question to include this, but you may have better luck opening a new question when you're ready. Best of luck.
